# how to increase speed of loading treeview nodes from a table using delphi

Tags: database, performance, delphi, treeview, ado

It's simple to load treeview nodes from table using a recursive function, but it takes a long time for huge data.
I have a table with these fields: ***id, title, parentid***  : that keeps treeview nodes in N level.

This table has more than 70000 rows. When i fill treeview from this table it take a long time (about 9 mins) for completion.

Is there a beter solution to increase loading speed?

Comment: Loading e.g. levels>2 only on expanding the parent ... using Treeview.Items.BeginUpdate/Endupdate ...

Comment: Use a virtual paradigm: load root nodes only and the rest on demand

Comment: Yep, virtual control is the solution

Comment: @Netlog - Why do you need to load 70000 rows at once? Does not make sense. How many nodes can a user view at one time? 50? 100? Why load them all at once?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: please back to my question (i did emped my code with TreeView) and let me know how i can do it using VirtualStringTree

Comment: I reverted your question. Your edit changed the question from, "Why is populating a tree view control slow, and how can I speed it up?" to "Please teach me how to use VTT." Stack Overflow is not a site where you keep changing the question and ask us to teach you all sorts of skills. One question at a time. And to learn VTT, read the copious documentation and examples that are easily found by websearch.

Comment: I really mean it. Do not change the question. You've asked a question and have two solid answers to the question you asked. Do not change the question completely. By all means edit to improve the question, add clarifications etc. But do not change it totally.

Answer (score 5):

You can try TreeView.Items.BeginUpdate/EndUpdate.

But storing 70000 rows in visual control is a questionable idea. Have you considered Virtual TreeView or another way to show only small subset of the data table?

Comment: i did test VirtualTreeView or TVirtualStringTree , but it's not useful for this purpose , since it can create milions of nodes only for a node and can't create 70000 nodes in N level

Comment: have you idea to fast load nodes in N level?

Comment: @Netlog I'll tell you the result of you Begin/EndUpdate test now. With 70000 nodes, your performance will never be acceptable until you switch to virtual paradigm.

Comment: @Netlog You cannot see thousands of nodes simultaneously, and VT maintains only visible nodes - it increases speed drastically

Answer (score 2):

The standard TTreeView gets slow very quickly as size increases. VirtualTreeview is a perfect solution and can handle millions of nodes without degradation.

Comment: i did test VirtualTreeView or TVirtualStringTree , but it's not useful for this purpose , since it can create milions of nodes only for a node and can't create 70000 nodes in N level

Comment: have you idea to fast load nodes in N level?

Comment: I'm sure that VTT will do you you want if only you learn how to use it.

Comment: @Netlog: that is not true. VTV has no limitations as to where the nodes are created. The `RootNodeCount` determines the number of top-level nodes. Number of child nodes is determined by calling the `InitChildren` event.

Comment: Dear Experts;
i'm newbie in VirtualStringTree.
i did edit my post with Treeview filling ,please let me know how i can do it with VST

Comment: @Smasher: please back to my question (i did embed my code with TreeView) and let me know , how i can do it using VT

Comment: Download VTV, open attached help and find-out chapters in the content: A little code repository by John Knipper and Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple extension to the TreeView control. It is very fast. It moves internal storage to a Dictionary which makes a huge difference. In my real world example I have 100000 records that I need to load. It took 37 minutes before, but now it takes 2.2 seconds!!

You can find example and code on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/679563/Fast-TreeView

Ah, sorry, I missed the Deplhi part. My example is for C# WindowsForms ....